# What is the difference between Log4j, SLF4J and Logback?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am little bit confused by these three logger libraries. It seems like that they can do the similar thing in Java logging...

Comment: They do similar things. They have different APIs. I would use the one you like best. BTW have a look at log4j2 rather than log4j.

Comment: @PeterLawrey With the exception of slf4j, which isn't a logger in itself (it is a facade to provide a consistent api to *another* logger).

Comment: Why the question gets 2negative votes?

Comment: Some benchmark here: https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-java-logging-frameworks/

Comment: Welcome to the bazaar !

Answer (score 165, accepted):

*Check out their home pages:*

[**SLF4J**](http://www.slf4j.org/) - The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a **simple facade or abstraction**<sup>1</sup> for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging, logback, log4j) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

<sup>1) It is not itself a logging library, but a generic interface to one of many logging libraries.</sup>

[**Log4j 1.2**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) - Welcome to Apache log4j, a **logging library** for Java.

[**Logback**](http://logback.qos.ch/) - Logback is **intended as a successor to the popular log4j** project, picking up where log4j leaves off.

[**Log4j 2**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) - Apache Log4j 2 is an **upgrade to Log4j** that provides significant improvements over its predecessor, Log4j 1.x, and **provides many of the improvements available in Logback** while fixing some inherent problems in Logback's architecture.

*At least, that's what they all say of themselves.*

Comment: So with SLF4J as a facade, we can use either log4j or logback or <any other compatible logging framework>. Is it?

Comment: @Shekhar yes that's correct

Comment: It is not quite correct that SLF4J is not a logging library. It is a logging library, in particular when using the slf4j-simple provider.

Comment: @PhilippeCloutier No one considers SLF4J a "logging library". It is an API. The Simple Logger it provides is rarely used.

Answer (score 12):

This link : https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/logback-slf4j-log4j2-understanding-them-and-learn-how-to-use-d33deedd0c46

Explains the differences in detail.

Quoting from there

**Slf4j**

> So Basically Simple Logging Facade for Java serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

**log4j2**

> Log4j,Logback and java.util.Logger are logging libraries which actually write the logs and have their own pros and cons. As industry standards are Log4j2 and logback

I would recommend going through the blog. It provides all the glory details how both are used with adapter.

Comment: The article you reference has some valuable information but is of low quality. It includes incorrect information (including a major mistake reported in a comment). It has some interesting graphics, but I assume some are in violation of SLF4J's copyrights. I'm therefore downvoting this to favor Andreas's far from perfect but IMO better answer.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is far from easy, and only covers some of the main elements of the Java ecosystem's ridiculously complicated logging. I do not know that ecosystem enough to fully describe it, but describing the current situation well and how it came to be would surely require days/weeks of work to write what would resemble a book.

Here is a very **short, surely simplistic** answer focusing on the elements you mentioned.

**Log4j** appeared as a flexible logging library in 2001.

**Logback** was developed as a [more powerful](https://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) alternative to Log4j from 2006 to 2011. The **Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)** was developed between 2005 and 2006 as [a superior alternative](https://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html) to [Apache/Jakarta] Commons Logging (JCL). Logback and SLF4J are complementary (they can be used together, or not).

Perhaps because Logback and SLF4J are to a small degree commercial, the Apache Foundation released in 2014 a major upgrade to Log4j. **Log4j 2 is somewhat comparable to Logback+SLF4J**, in that it provides a facade API (log4j-api, comparable to SLF4J) as well as an implementation (log4j-core, comparable to Logback).

If the above seems to contradict other sources, that may be because Log4j version 1 was very different and remains in use, so sources describing "Log4j" may in fact still describe Log4j 1.

Comment: Nice answer! Log42 (or better Log4j2 API+Log4j2 Core) is even **exactly** as SLF4J+Logback: both are developed by a single entity (Ceki Gülcü for SLF4J+Logback, the Apache Logging Services PMC for Log4j2 API+Log4j2 Core), both backends are mainly driven by changes in their API (and viceversa). Also both APIs can work with both backends.

Comment: Log4j and SLF4J+Logback are *comparable*, but while Log4j is one solution, I would consider Logback and SLF4J as highly *complementary* products. Unlike Log4j, SLF4J for instance features slf4j-simple, which allows to use it alone, without Logback. Whereas Logback offers logback-classic, a module which enables integration with SLF4J.

It may be a nuance, but I'd rather not oversimplify, because the topic is already complicated enough!

Comment: That is IMHO a misconception, due to the fact that Log4j2 API and Log4j2 Core share a common name. Like SLF4J, Log4j2 API has a simple binding (it is included in `log4j-api`) and bindings to all major logging frameworks (i.e. Logback, `java.util.logging` and JBoss LogManager). It only lacks a binding to Log4j 1.x for obvious reasons.

Comment: Hum, interesting. If log4j-api *includes* "a simple binding" to itself, I guess that's more of an implementation that a *binding proper*, but regardless, I can't find any documentation of that. It's not that I really question your say, but surely such a feature would be documented somewhere?

Comment: Documentation is hard to come by. To configure a [`SimpleLoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/simple/SimpleLoggerContext.html) you use system properties, which are [documented here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#system-properties). From time to time a [question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72115612/11748454) pops up.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thank you Piotr