# Where does slf4j-jdk14 get logging configurations from?

Tags: logging, properties, log4j, slf4j, properties-file

Where does slf4j-jdk14 get configurations from?
I am using

```
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.8.0-alpha2'
```

and importing

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

In my java file my code is as below:

```
Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppTest.class);
logger.info("This is my login!!");
```

I am getting logs genereated but dont know where it is taking properties from. I want to disable Info logs from my property file as well as put those logs to file. I dont have any property file or log4j xml file.

Answer (score 2):

`slf4j` is `Simple Logging Facade for Java`.

There is a reason you can't set configuration.
please, visit this link : [When should SLF4J be used?](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#when)

so it can only print on standard output like console. If you want to log and save it on external file then you'd better use logging framework like `log4j2`, `logback`,
If you want to know about difference `log4j2` and other `logging framework` then please visit below links.

1. [What is the difference between log4j, slf4j and logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562965/what-is-the-difference-between-log4j-slf4j-and-logback)
2. [The SLF4J interfaces and their various adapters](http://www.slf4j.org/images/concrete-bindings.png)

If you use `log4j2` then follow below texts.

1. Set configuration.
   **log4j2.xml**

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    ...
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        ... <AppenderRef> ...
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

2. Change Log level to edit `Root level`
   For example, edit level optioin from`<Root level="info">` to `<Root level="error">`

Comment: Yes I fixed this y'day and it was the same reason you mentioned :)

Comment: @YatinKanyal Good!

Answer (score 1):

Using logback instead of slf4j-jdk14 solved my prob

```
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
```